# How to move a slotted child component to its parent without losing its reference in Stencil.js?

Tags: stenciljs

I have a Navbar which consists of nested navbar-items. Each navbar-item can have multiple nested navbar-items.

This is my html structure:

```
   <ifx-navbar>
        <ifx-navbar-item slot="left-item">
         Nav Item
             <ifx-navbar-item>
              Second Layer
                <ifx-navbar-item>Third Layer</ifx-navbar-item>
             </ifx-navbar-item>
        </ifx-navbar-item>
        <ifx-navbar-item slot="left-item">Nav Item</ifx-navbar-item>
    </ifx-navbar>
```

Inside the Navbar, I am using  to position the nested child components where I want them to be.

```
 <div class="navbar__container-left-content-navigation-group">
   <slot name='left-item' />
 </div>
```

Still inside Navbar, I have my mobile resolution container

```
  <div class="navbar__sidebar-top-row-wrapper">
       <slot name='mobile-menu-top' />
       <slot name='first-layer' />
  </div>
```

Still inside Navbar, when resolution is 800px or less, I take the navbar-items, and change their slot name so they can move into the mobile menu.

```
componentWillLoad() {
    const mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 800px)');
    mediaQueryList.addEventListener('change', (e) => this.moveNavItemsToSidebar(e));
  }
  moveNavItemsToSidebar(e) {
    if (e.matches) {
      /* The viewport is 800px wide or less */
      const leftMenuItems = this.el.querySelectorAll('[slot="left-item"]')
      for(let i = 0; i < leftMenuItems.length; i++) { 
        leftMenuItems[i].setAttribute('slot', 'mobile-menu-top')
        this.getChildren(leftMenuItems[i].shadowRoot)
      }
    } else {
      /* The viewport is more than 800px wide */
      const leftMenuItems = this.el.querySelectorAll('[slot="mobile-menu-top"]')
      for(let i = 0; i < leftMenuItems.length; i++) { 
        leftMenuItems[i].setAttribute('slot', 'left-item')
      }
    }
  }

 getChildren(el) { 
    const childComponents = el.querySelectorAll('ifx-navbar-item')
    if(childComponents.length !== 0) { 
      for(let i = 0; i < childComponents.length; i++) { 
        childComponent.setAttribute('slot', 'first-layer')
      }
    }
  }
```

The logic inside `moveNavItemsToSidebar()` works great! The `navbar-item` that are direct children of the `Navbar` move to the new place when their `slot` name has been changed, but now what I need to do is to take THEIR children, and move them as well! And this is what does not work. The logic inside `getChildren(el)` is correct, and the `slot` name is added, but the component is not moved.

I suspected this is because of the `shadow DOM` since mine is enabled, so I tried 2 more things.
I tried to emit the `navbar-item` as an event, Listen for it inside the `Navbar` and then change its `slot`, but it did not work either.
Then I tried to Listen for it, grab it, and then put it inside an array defined inside `Navbar`, and only then change the `slot` name, but it did not work either.

So, my question is, how can I make this work? I need to grab all of the navbar-items nested inside the first navbar-item, take them out, and put them inside a separate div container without using their reference. Using slots worked but only for the first parent navbar-item. I need to do the same for their children too!

Comment: Slim it down to an MVP, without Stencil. Sounds like you are trying to move slotted content as if DOM was **moved** to a slot, while it remains in lightDOM and is only **_reflected_** to a slot.

Comment: What is MVP and what do you mean without Stencil? 
I am trying to move a slotted component into a slot of its parent.

Comment: a [minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Don't know if you can run Stencil here in a snippet.

Comment: There have been a couple fixes for slots in v4.10+, so make sure to update and test again. And you can use Stencil with https://webcomponents.dev/ (scroll down to "Select your Template" and select Stencil")

Comment: @Thomas I am still using v4.5, but I don't think the slots are the issue here ,but rather the shadow DOM. Do you think the new version will allow me to change the slot of a nested component, and move it to its parent?

Comment: Not sure about the specifics, but the fixed issues seem to be about dynamic slot changes, so I'd say it's worth a try. Here's [the changelog](https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#-450-2023-10-16)

Comment: Thanks. I think I'll change my approach and find a different solution. I am doing a multi-layered sidebar menu, where clicking on the first item in the menu slides in a second layer of menu, which has the items from the first menu-item and so on. So since the items are slotted inside each menu-item, I was trying to get them out and move them by changing the slots, but couldn't. So what I will do now is just implement the 2nd layer inside each menu-item rather than trying to move them up to the parent navbar.